# xsl:number - Excluding certain elements

Tags: xsl-fo

In xsl fo I need to label/count an element called `prcitem1` using `xsl:number`, but I only want to target `prcitem1` elements that have a second descendant named `para`.

The numbering works in the sense that the only labeled elements are the ones I just described, but if there is a `prcitem1` element that does not fit the criteria, it is still counted even though the label is not displayed. This causes the numbering to be incorrect, like it will start at B. instead of A. because the first `prcitem1` element does not fit the criteria but is still counted.

I am using `<xsl:number count="self::*[./prcitem1/para] format="A" from="task"`. Task is the containing element for `prcitem1` and I am counting from inside the `prcitem1` template. Anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: Are you working on ATA manuals? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have to count `prcitem1[para]` like this:

```
<xsl:number format="A" from="task" count="prcitem1[para]"/>
```

Here's an example. It might not match yours exactly, but should be close...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <task>
        <prclist1>
            <prcitem1>
                <prcitem>
                    <para>prcitem 1A</para>
                </prcitem>
            </prcitem1>
            <prcitem1>
                <prcitem>
                    <para>prcitem 2A</para>
                </prcitem>
            </prcitem1>
            <prcitem1/>
            <prcitem1>
                <prcitem>
                    <para>prcitem 4A</para>
                </prcitem>
            </prcitem1>
        </prclist1>
        <prclist1>
            <prcitem1>
                <prcitem>
                    <para>prcitem 1B</para>
                </prcitem>
            </prcitem1>
            <prcitem1/>
            <prcitem1>
                <prcitem>
                    <para>prcitem 3B</para>
                </prcitem>
            </prcitem1>
            <prcitem1>
                <prcitem>
                    <para>prcitem 4B</para>
                </prcitem>
            </prcitem1>
        </prclist1>
    </task>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0** (Would work as 1.0 as-is.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
                    <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="prclist1">
        <fo:list-block font-size="10pt" provisional-distance-between-starts="24pt" space-before=".1in" space-after=".1in" keep-with-next.within-page="always">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:list-block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="prcitem1[prcitem/para]">
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()" font-size="12pt" font-weight="bold">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:number format="A" from="task" count="prcitem1[prcitem/para]"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()" font-size="12pt">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="prcitem/para"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**FO Output**

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
         <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:list-block font-size="10pt"
                        provisional-distance-between-starts="24pt"
                        space-before=".1in"
                        space-after=".1in"
                        keep-with-next.within-page="always">
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()" font-size="12pt" font-weight="bold">
                  <fo:block>A</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()" font-size="12pt">
                  <fo:block>prcitem 1A</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()" font-size="12pt" font-weight="bold">
                  <fo:block>B</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()" font-size="12pt">
                  <fo:block>prcitem 2A</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()" font-size="12pt" font-weight="bold">
                  <fo:block>C</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()" font-size="12pt">
                  <fo:block>prcitem 4A</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
         </fo:list-block>
         <fo:list-block font-size="10pt"
                        provisional-distance-between-starts="24pt"
                        space-before=".1in"
                        space-after=".1in"
                        keep-with-next.within-page="always">
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()" font-size="12pt" font-weight="bold">
                  <fo:block>A</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()" font-size="12pt">
                  <fo:block>prcitem 1B</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()" font-size="12pt" font-weight="bold">
                  <fo:block>B</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()" font-size="12pt">
                  <fo:block>prcitem 3B</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()" font-size="12pt" font-weight="bold">
                  <fo:block>C</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()" font-size="12pt">
                  <fo:block>prcitem 4B</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
         </fo:list-block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

**PDF Output**

[image]